# Not able to complete Trailhead Challenge - Process Automation()

Tags: community, workflow, visual-workflow, sales-cloud

Continuous Error
[image: Continuous Error]

Not able to complete the following challenge - 
[image]

Following are my screenshot - 
Workflow Rule

[image: Workflow Rule]

Field Update

[image: Field Update]

Task

[image: Task]

Comment: every time when it is edited to meet criteria

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... The problem was in field update

Comment: I was updating wrong field..... @christian

Answer (score 1):

Your field update is changing the case status, not checking the Escalated checkbox.